# Issue in XPath - considering the hidden elements and giving wrong count

Tags: c#, xpath

I have 2 pages, which has similar tag but is having different tags when an element is hidden

Currently when I'm using below XPath - it is taking hidden element too, which I don't want

XPATH:

var sides_by_v2_term = "//div[@id = 'product-carousel']//a[contains(@rel, '/product/carousel/select/Field/')]";

I want only those elements that are not hidden but I'm getting 6 count from DOM Page 1 - And I need 5 count(i.e hidden element should not come")

Code of navigating all elements - issue as count coming 6

```
     for (int i = 1; i <= sides_Count; i++)
            {
                //var side_by = By.XPath($"{element_sides_by_xpath}[{i}]");
                var side_by = By.XPath($"{canvasView.element_sides.locator}[{i}]");


                //var temp = Driver.TryFind(side_by, 500);
                Driver.Click(side_by);}
```

DOM Elements Page 1:

```xml
<div id="items" class="items carousel-items" style="outline: green dotted 2px !important;" xpath="1">
    <a class="carousel-item js-carousel-item active" href="javascript:" rel="/product/carousel/select/Field/0">
        <div id="productfield0" class="product-carousel-field js-carousel-item-wrapper">
            <span class="carousel-item-image" id="fieldCanvasWrapper0">
                <canvas width="100" height="100" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"/>
            </span>
            <p id="fieldLable0">Front Left</p>
        </div>
        <span class="" data-fieldindex="0"/>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-item js-carousel-item" href="javascript:" rel="/product/carousel/select/Field/1">
        <div id="productfield1" class="product-carousel-field js-carousel-item-wrapper">
            <span class="carousel-item-image" id="fieldCanvasWrapper1">
                <canvas width="100" height="100" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"/>
            </span>
            <p id="fieldLable1">Front Right</p>
        </div>
        <span class="" data-fieldindex="1"/>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-item js-carousel-item" href="javascript:" rel="/product/carousel/select/Field/2">
        <div id="productfield2" class="product-carousel-field js-carousel-item-wrapper">
            <span class="carousel-item-image" id="fieldCanvasWrapper2">
                <canvas width="100" height="100" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"/>
            </span>
            <p id="fieldLable2">Right Belt</p>
        </div>
        <span class="" data-fieldindex="2"/>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-item js-carousel-item" href="javascript:" rel="/product/carousel/select/Field/3">
        <div id="productfield3" class="product-carousel-field js-carousel-item-wrapper">
            <span class="carousel-item-image" id="fieldCanvasWrapper3">
                <canvas width="100" height="100" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"/>
            </span>
            <p id="fieldLable3">Left Belt</p>
        </div>
        <span class="" data-fieldindex="3"/>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-item js-carousel-item" href="javascript:" rel="/product/carousel/select/Field/4" style="">
        <div id="productfield4" class="product-carousel-field js-carousel-item-wrapper">
            <span class="carousel-item-image" id="fieldCanvasWrapper4">
                <canvas width="100" height="100" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"/>
            </span>
            <p id="fieldLable4">Back</p>
        </div>
        <span class="" data-fieldindex="4"/>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-item js-carousel-item" href="javascript:" rel="/product/carousel/select/Field/5" style="">
        <div id="productfield5" class="product-carousel-field js-carousel-item-wrapper js-hide-3d-carousel-item" style="">
            <span class="carousel-item-image" id="fieldCanvasWrapper5">
                <canvas width="100" height="100" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"/>
            </span>
            <p id="fieldLable5"/>
        </div>
        <span class="warnings" data-fieldindex="5"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

DOM Page 2:

```xml
<div id="items" class="carousel-items less-itmes" style="left: 0px;">
    <a href="javascript:" rel="/product/carousel/select/Field/0" class="active">
        <span class="product-carousel-field"><img src="/estore/preview/initialthumb?productId=30&amp;systemName=&amp;productName=Cushion_30new&amp;pvers=211&amp;currentFieldIndex=0&amp;listOfOptionValues=bas-26:817,bas-259:4,bas-431:2572&amp;templateChanged=false&amp;galleryId=s3_2020.04.21_0c8776e8-fab4-4f40-bcf6-6fc1b22e3e2a&amp;tid=11824ea5-dac6-4666-8d2d-156e40121d1e&amp;viewName=&amp;designName=&amp;version=0"/><br/>Front</span>
        <span data-fieldindex="0">&nbsp;</span>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:" rel="/product/carousel/select/Field/1" class="">
        <span class="product-carousel-field"><img src="/estore/preview/initialthumb?productId=30&amp;systemName=&amp;productName=Cushion_30new&amp;pvers=211&amp;currentFieldIndex=1&amp;listOfOptionValues=bas-26:817,bas-259:4,bas-431:2572&amp;templateChanged=false&amp;galleryId=s3_2020.04.21_0c8776e8-fab4-4f40-bcf6-6fc1b22e3e2a&amp;tid=11824ea5-dac6-4666-8d2d-156e40121d1e&amp;viewName=&amp;designName=&amp;version=0"/><br/>Back</span>
        <span data-fieldindex="1">&nbsp;</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say hidden I assume you mean not having the class of active. Perhaps make your question slightly clearer. Also you could format the html better and perhaps remove the superfluous tags from the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I right to assume that whether an item is hidden is determined by the class `js-hide-3d-carousel-item`?

If so this XPath would exclude that respective `a`-tag:

```
//a[contains(@rel , '/product/carousel/select/Field/') and div[not(contains(@class, 'js-hide-3d-carousel-item'))]]
```

As string operations like `contains()`are quite expensive in XPath pre filtering (like you did) with the parent `div` is a good idea:

```
//div[@id = 'items']/a[div[not(contains(@class, 'js-hide-3d-carousel-item'))]]
```

(N.B. I did not use `//div[@id = 'product-carousel']` as it's not in your sample XML, instead I used `//div[@id = 'items']`in the above example.

Comment: //div[@id = 'items']/a[div[not(contains(@class, 'js-hide-3d-carousel-item'))]] - It worked for my DOM Page 1 Now what will happen is the same XPath can not be used for DOM Page 2

Comment: In My DOM Page 2 - Hidden field will have Span tag like <a><span></span></a> instead of div
So do u have any suggestion where xpath will check either div/span tag not having class "js-hide-3d-carousel-item"?

Comment: Well, in your DOM Page 2 example the html structure of both items is identical, except for the `@class='active'`; in this case the answer by @mattbloke should work, see below at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61366088/13091015

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got the gist of what you are trying to do.
You don't need to select the div elements first you can go straight to your anchor tags. I've amended your xpath to not select anchors without the class active.

```
//a[contains(@rel, '/product/carousel/select/Field/') and not(contains(@class, 'active'))]
```

Comment: This won;t work as I need to exclude only hidden element

Comment: You don't actual say what designates a hidden element so not sure how to help. The xpath I suggested returns 5 elements is this not what you want?